# RegEx: Replace . with - in IDs

Tags: regex, replace

I'm not an RegEx expert and I tried my best with http://gskinner.com/RegExr/, but I can't find the proper solution. Here is my problem:

I've got a bunch of HTML files with IDs like

```
<span id="listing0.title.moreinfo">bla</span>
```

There are other IDs without a **.**

```
<span id="listing0">bla</span>
```

My question:
How do I replace all **.** with **-**? IDs without a **.** should not be changed.

I'm sure it's not the best solution, but this is how I find all IDs:

```
/( id=")(([\w\d])*)(.*([\w\d])*)"/gi
```

Comment: What language do you plan to execute the regular expression?

Comment: I was hoping to do it directly in Notepad++ or Eclipse for all HTML pages.

Comment: I used Eclipse, replaced (id=")([\w\d-]+)(\.)([\w\d\.]+") with $1$2-$4, ran it a few times and done.

Answer (score 1):

I do it in PHP this way, but the process is same.

```
// pattern to find all the ids
$reg = '/id="([^"]+)"/';
$str = '<span id="listing0.title.moreinfo">bla</span>';
// find all the ids. second first subgroup will contain the id string.
preg_match($reg, $str, $m);

// replace . with - with simple string replace function.
echo str_replace('/\./', '-', $m[0]);
```

The standard id string finding regex would be `/id="([^"]+)"/gi`

Comment: Thank you for the string finding regex! But is there a way to replace the dots without passing the string to a variable, just with a regex?

Comment: I dont think its possible in an editor like eclipse or notepad++ unless there is an external plug-in.

Answer (score 0):

This works in C#:

```
var html = @"<span id=""listing0.title.moreinfo"">bla</span>
             <span id=""listing0"">bla</span>";

var pattern = @"id=("".*?"")";

html = Regex.Replace(html, pattern, delegate(Match match)
                                    {
                                        return match.Value.Replace('.', '-');
                                    });

Console.WriteLine(html);
Console.ReadKey();
```

Answer (score 0):

With Notepad++,

- search for : `id="(\w+)\.(\w+)\.(\w+)"`
- replace with : `id="\1-\2-\3"`